# Upgrading to Nvidia GPU from an AMD GPU

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, gpu-driver

so I have recently ordered a GTX 1650 Super (To be specific, the PNY Single-fan variant) as a small upgrade from my RX 570. The 1650 Super still hasn't arrived (And shouldn't for another ~5 days after the time of writing) and while waiting for the card to arrive I have had a realization: I'm going to have to remove the currently installed AMDGPU drivers and install the Nvidia Proprietary drivers, so what exactly would this process be? (Yes, I am aware I probably should have done some research about this prior to ordering the card, my bad)

I'm a Linux novice and, to add to the confusion, this is also my first time performing a GPU upgrade.

Relevant software information:

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.1 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic

GPU Driver Version: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall mesa-va-drivers, mesa-vdpau-drivers and mesa-vulkan-drivers packages in order to install the NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers in Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics driver to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. In order to install the NVIDIA proprietary graphics drivers for the GeForce GTX 1650 Super graphics card open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: Posting this as an extra detail for others in potentially similar situations: The X server would immediately crash with the new Nvidia card installed, forcing these commands to be run in a TTY via ctrl-alt-F(number)

Comment: @Zed In the case of a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and later on a new computer with a new Nvidia graphics card there exists an option of installing the proprietary graphics drivers by the Ubuntu installer. This option didn't crash on my computer. Of course your mileage may vary depending on your graphics card model, etc.